# Position :before pseudoclass in-between parent and child CSS

Tags: css

(Basically I'm trying to style a text field beyond its normal capabilities, including filler text which doesn't interact directly with the cursor.)

I wonder if it's possible to position (using `z-index` if possible) a `:before` element behind the child elements of the container element, but in front of the container background. (Maybe you'd understand in a bit)

HTML:

```
<div class="field" data-title="John">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.field{
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid gray;
}

.field:before{
    content:attr(data-title);
}

input[type="text"]{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

This displays correctly:

[image]

However, I'm concerned because you cannot focus the text field if your cursor is over the `:before` content (in this case, is the word "John").

I do understand that the `:before` can be styled with `pointer-events:none`, however, the "pointer-events" tag is not yet entirely cross-browser compatible.

Hopefully I made myself clear. Any help at all would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm reluctant to believe that HTML/CSS produces that image ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p4aps2cw/); given that `content` should only be used in pseudo-elements. So I don't know if you're using a browser with a non-standard implementation of CSS (for some reason), or if you've just mis-typed your CSS.

Comment: Oh, hold on a sec. I'll update the CSS.

Comment: And why are you not using [a label](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p4aps2cw/2/), or [placeholder](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p4aps2cw/1/)?

Comment: Well, a placeholder works quite well. (To be quite frank, I didn't even know it existed!) Thank you for your response.

Comment: But in the event that this uses a custom autocomplete script, somewhat like Google's, how would one go about doing something like that?